# Eclipse: source folder hierarchy missing a level, declared package does not match expected package

Tags: java, android, eclipse, buildpath

I am trying to import [LibreTasks](https://github.com/biotinker/LibreTasks) into Eclipse, however the project has a somewhat odd folder hierarchy. For instance, the path to the `libretasks.app.model` package is `src/app/model`.

`src` is on the build path, but Eclipse can’t resolve any class references and for every package declarations throws errors like

> The declared package "libretasks.app.model" does not match the expected package "app.model"

Is there any way I can tell Eclipse that `libretasks.app.model` package is not to be found in `src/libretasks/app/model`, but in `src/app/model`?

The obvious one would be to rearrange the folder hierarchy, but since I’m planning to contribute back, I don’t want to mess with that. Any way I can get Eclipse to work with the nonstandard layout?

Comment: I find myself genuinely curious how/if that builds *outside* of Eclipse.

Comment: The app’s on F-Droid, who apparently built it successfully (they have an APK), and the build recipe doesn’t have any special workarounds. AFAIK they use `ant` from the command line.